# How to install openjfx in Kali Linux?

Tags: java, kali-linux

Can anyone tell me how to install `openjfx` in Kali Linux to use `javafx` in my applications? I tried

```
apt-get install openjfx
```

but the package is unknown in the repository. If that package is unavailable, perhaps there is another option to view rich text webpages in a webview with `openjdk`.

Answer (score 1):

As Kali (1.x) is based on Debian Wheezy and there is not `openjfx` in Wheezy's repo, you can't normally install it by `apt-get`. However, it could be compile from source follow [the offical instruction on OpenJDK Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) (you can consider your system as Ubuntu 12.04 since they share the same kernel version).

Another option is to upgrade your system. Since Kali is built on top of Debian, it's safe enough to use Debian's repo and upgrade to Debian Jessie. Then you'd need to [enable Jessie's backports repo](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2) and install `openjfx` by `apt-get -t jessie-backports install openjfx`.

Comment: Kali _strongly_ discourages from using non-Kali repositories: http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories